# Select value from view to controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, model-view-controller

I'm trying to pass a selected value in a dropdown from my view to my controller so i can make a query later.

Here is my **view** with the select object:

```
 <Select class="selectsector" id="ColumnType" name="ColumnType">
    <option value=""> Select something </option>
    <option value="">  option 1 </option>
    <option value="">  option 2 </option>
 </select>
```

Then according to documentation and a lot of answer/examples i'm trying to get the value from the select on this line:

```
 {{ route('trend', ['ColumnType' => $ColumnType->ColumnType])}}
```

**My route:**

```
 Route::get('kitysoftware/ColumnType/{ColumnType}', [
 "uses" => 'SubSectorsBPIsDataController@TrendFilter',
 "as" => 'trend'
  ]);
```

**My controller:**

```
  public function TrendFilter($ColumnType)
  {
  $SelectedTrend = DB::table('SubSectorsBPIsData')->select('SectorID', 'ColumnType')->where('ColumnType', $ColumnType)->get();
    echo $selectedTrend; //or whatever else i want to do        
}
```

**Error**
I keep getting: Undefined variable: ColumnType (View: ...
I have tried to change several variables names in that line: 
         {{ route('trend', ['ColumnType' => $ColumnType->ColumnType])}} 
*Where does it comes from that undefined variable: $ColumnType ?
I'm not reloading the page since i want to collect several dropdowns values and then make the query. 
Not sure if i got the right approach, maybe there is a better way to make it work. 
JavaScript maybe?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify: 
The code you write in your views is HTML. If you use the `{{...}}` the code in the braces is evaluated in php first. All of this happens on your server. The `$ColumnType`-Variable does not exist when this happens (and also not later). The user has not even seen your site, when your server tries to know what the value of the variable is.

To send data back from the user to your controller, I suggest using a form:

```html
<form action="{{route('trend')}}" method="POST">
    <select class="selectsector" id="ColumnType" name="ColumnType">
        <option value=""> Select something </option>
        <option value="option1">option1</option>
        <option value="option2">option2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit"></input>
</form>
```

When the form is submitted the browser will automatically send back a request with the parameter `ColumnType` to your controller. If you want to use POST, change your route definition to `Route::post`. You can access the value of the parameter like this:

```
public function TrendFilter(Request $request)
{
    $selectedOption = $request->input('ColumnType');
}
```

**EDIT** 
Addressing your comments:

If you take the POST approach, you won't need the `{ColumnType}`-subpath in the URL. The selected option gets passed via the request, and is not visible in the URL.

If you want the parameters in the URL (this can be useful, if you want to share the site by sharing the URL), then use GET. Your browser will then append the selected options as parameters to the URL. Like this:

```
?options=option1
```

Both ways, you can access the selected option in your controller like I described above.

You are getting the "Route Not Found"-Error, because the `route( name )`-function takes the name of the route as argument. In your case this would be `trend`, set by the 'as' in your route definition.

Also note, that you probably will need a second handler in your controller, to accept the form feedback and do the query. You can then redirect to the previous page (same view) with updated values (`data`) and keep the selected options (`withInput()`).

```
public function acceptForm(Request $request){
    $selectedOption = $request->input('ColumnType');
    data = doQuery($selectedOption)...
    return redirect()->back()->with(data)->withInput();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. By using POST method does it means that user have to submit the form? Because what i want is just to get several dropdown values and then submit the form but i guess it makes sense to grab the value like you're saying.

Comment: POST and GET are request methods, normally POST is used to send a filled out form. It says nothing about who submits the form.

You can put more than one dropdown in a form, or use `<select multiple>`.
I don't fully understand, what you want to achieve. Maybe you can describe it more detailed in your question?

Comment: Hi again @streamfighter  
After reading/testing more i came to the question, what do i put on my route when submiting a form?
I mean, i want to capture the selected value on the <select> and send it to the controller. Then in the controller (after a few operations) i want to display results in the same view, so i don't really need another view file. 
**Current route** 
`Route::get('kitysoftware/ColumnType/{ColumnType}', 'SubSectorsBPIsDataController@TrendSelector');`
**And my form**

Comment: contine...
**And my form**
 `<form action="{{route('kitysoftware/ColumnType/{ColumnType}')}}" method="POST">`
**Error** I keep getting route not defined. Tried several routes and all i can manage to get is a 404 error :( Can you clarify or point me to any video/post where i can get more information about it? Thanks again

Comment: Even if i change my route to a new view.blade.php file all i get is a blank page, is  frustrating that is just not passing the variable value to the controller :(

Comment: @gallo2000sv I made an edit above, to answer your comments